# Best Translation method - ASP.NET VS2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, content-management-system, translation

Currently I am doing a CMS and I want to include multi language support. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options here.

1. use database
2. use resource files.

pros and cons

1. at each page request your web site will run some database queries. If hit of web site is high that can be a problem. Adding and removing language items are easy.
2. Web page uses resource file (it is xml format as far as i remember). even if database connection is down your visitors can see the page and they will see a message "There is no database connection now" or someting else like that.

I suggest 2. one.

Comment: So everytime someone adds new content in multiple languages in the CMS the resource file should be edited? I think that's a very bad choice.